# API for Code Analysis window in VS2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions

Is there any api to reach the **code analysis** output tool window in Visual Studio 2012?
I can't find anything in the docs or from ILSpy search.

I want to read data from it.

Here's a page with an image of it: http://codemlia.com/blog/post/2012/09/15/code-analysis-ca0053-building-vs-2010-projects-in-vs-2012.aspx

Comment: Which window are you referring to? And define "reach"? Do you want to output data, read data...?

Comment: @JasonMalinowski There's an image of it here: http://codemlia.com/blog/post/2012/09/15/code-analysis-ca0053-building-vs-2010-projects-in-vs-2012.aspx
I want to read data from it.

Comment: Implementing a solution based on information gathered by reverse engineering might infringe the license agreement (-: But have you tried to use this tool: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38196 It will give you the same results.